# Weird timing display in WhatsApp chat

Tags: whatsapp

On WhatsApp, how is it that I've replied to a message **BEFORE** having received it?

[image]

Comment: Is the time on your phone correct? have you tried setting the time a few minutes forwards or backwards to see if the issue persists?

Comment: yup time is fine. synced with network time

Comment: I wonder does WhatsApp use the time from your friends phone to display his messages (or the time from the WhatsApp server)? Maybe the time on your phone and their time is out of sync

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Install an Internet Time app and check your phones offset.

Answer (score 1):

The time on your phone is manually set. WhatsApp use the time of your phone when it display the time of the messages you send. When you receive messages WhatsApp use a time server to set the time.

To solve this, update the time of your phone so that it is correct.

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Change the time so that it is correct.

Comment: No my time is not manually set...

Comment: When set to "Automatic time", the only automatic thing is the daylight saving. The time is still manually set and not synchronized against any time server. It's very sad :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem. Your phone and your friend's phone's times are slightly different, so the times will sometimes show like that. This also happens in Voxer, Messaging...

Comment: I doubt it uses local phone time else if my friend was in a different timezone, you'd never have messages in the right order

Comment: Hmmm... That's a good point... however, this makes it look like it goes off of phone time... http://www.askmefast.com/How_to_change_the_time_on_whatsapp-qna815250.html#q4479113

Comment: As far as what you said on the time zones, might the region setting of your phone correct that?

Comment: My region is set to Canada which is accurate...

Comment: Can you set your time to manual, then set it to an incorrect time? Then send a WatsApp message and see what time it displays. This would let you know if WatsApp uses local phone time or network time.